# get ip address using os.system in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, os.system

Im new to python and Im trying to get the IP Address of my network card using the following:

```
import sys
import os



ip_address = os.system('/sbin/ifconfig ens33 | grep "inet" |awk '/inet / { print $2 }' | cut -d":" -f2')
```

However it returns the following error:

```
ip_address = os.system('/sbin/ifconfig ens33 | grep "inet" |awk '/inet / { print $2 }' | cut -d":" -f2')
                                                                                 ^
```

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

If I just have in up to here it get some of the output:

```
ip_address = os.system('/sbin/ifconfig ens33 | grep "inet" ')
```

inet 192.168.130.130  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.130.255
inet6 fe80::97b9:2816:c3a3:e02e  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20

Is there a way to do this using os and sys ?

Comment: Your inner single quotation marks need to be escaped.

Comment: Even if you fix the syntax errors this isn't going to work...`os.system()` does not return the output of the command. You're going to want to look at the `subprocess` module.

Comment: If you don't want to concern yourself with proper escaping of inner quotation marks, enclose the whole command line between a pair of three-quotes `"""`. However, why do you need to feed the results of `ifconfig` through `grep` and `awk`? You can just process it in Python...

Comment: Thanks Klaus, Ive altered it now to be:

ip_address = os.system('/sbin/ifconfig ens33 | grep "inet" |awk \'/inet / { print $2 }\' | cut -d":" -f2')

That prints out :

192.168.130.130
0

How do I get it to not print the "0"

Comment: "Is there a way to do this using os and sys ?" you shouldn't be using `os.sytem`, use the `subprocess` module

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way:

```py
import subprocess

cmd = """/sbin/ifconfig eth0 | grep "inet" | awk '/inet / { print $2 }' | cut -d: -f2"""
r = subprocess.run(cmd, shell=True, capture_output=True, universal_newlines=True)
private_ip = r.stdout.strip()

>>> obfuscate_ip(private_ip)  # see footnote
'55.3.93.202'
```

(For your case: use `ens33` instead of `eth0`).

That said, you are better off using `socket`:

```py
import socket

def get_private_ip():
    with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM) as st:
        st.settimeout(0.0)
        try:
            st.connect(('8.8.8.8', 80))
            ip = st.getsockname()[0]
        except socket.error:
            ip = '127.0.0.1'
    return ip

private_ip2 = get_private_ip()

>>> obfuscate_ip(private_ip2)
'55.3.93.202'
```

And:

```py
assert private_ip2 == private_ip
```

---

Footnote: I don't like to reveal my actual IP address (even if just the private one). Thus:

```py
import numpy as np
import contextlib

@contextlib.contextmanager
def seed_context(seed):
    state = np.random.get_state()
    np.random.seed(seed)
    try:
        yield
    finally:
        np.random.set_state(state)

def obfuscate_ip(ip):
    with seed_context(id(obfuscate_ip) >> 16):
        mul = np.random.randint(1, 255, 4)
        off = np.random.randint(1, 255, 4)
        parts = (np.array([int(x) for x in ip.split('.')]) * mul + off) % 256
        return '.'.join(map(str, parts))
```

Comment: you should probably just use `subprocess.run()`

Answer (score 0):

`os.system` runs the command in the shell but does not return the output so that you can capture it into a variable. You need something like `subprocess.Popen` to get the command output.

```py
import subprocess

stdout, _ = subprocess.Popen("ifconfig", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()
stdout = stdout.decode() # above returned value is a binary string
```

Then you can filter out the stdout and get what you need.

If you have only one IP, it might be easier to use `hostname -I` command instead

Answer (score -1):

Make it simple and use the below command :-

```
import os 

print(os.system("ifconfig"))
```

Comment: This does not answer the question.